# Minishift on AWS EC2 --vm-driver generic fails for ssh handshake

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, minishift

Trying to setup minishift on AWS EC2 based on the guide - https://www.densify.com/blog/deploy-minishift-public-cloud/.
Control Machine [A] is on "AWS Linux" and Minishift [B] machine is on "RHEL 9"
After all steps, I verified the ssh from [A] to [B] which was successful.

But while running minishift start with - minishift start --remote-ipaddress {machine [B}} --remote-ssh-user ec2-user --remote-ssh-key /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa --vm-driver generic. it fails

---

[ec2-user@ip-10-248-81-143 ~]$ minishift start --remote-ipaddress 10.248.80.97 --remote-ssh-user ec2-user --remote-ssh-key /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa --vm-driver generic
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'generic' hypervisor ...
**Error creating ssh client: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain**

---